How do you browse a GitLab CI build after it fails?
Situtaion

I push code to my repo on my self-hosted GitLab server.
It triggers my runner to run my CI job.
The CI job fails.
Now I want to go investigate the scene of the crime.

Question
How can I get into the Docker (container? image? volume?) and look around at what files the CI job had available when it failed? For instance, the job might have failed with a message like "check foo.log for details." I have direct SSH access to the runner server, but I don't know where to look or how to get into the Docker e.g. to inspect foo.log.


How can I get into the Docker (container? image? volume?) and look around at what files the CI job had available when it failed?

You can't - the docker conatainer has been removed.
What you can do is add like a sleep 3600 to your .gitlab-ci.yml, and then you can hop in to the container while it is still running.

he job might have failed with a message like "check foo.log for details.

Add foo.log to build artefacts.

How do you browse a GitLab CI build after it fails?

Through the gitlab  web interface.

Adding every single file in the filesystem to the artifacts is not feasible. And the web interface doesn't have the files as far as I can tell. Is there no way to restart the container and connect to it? sleep 3600 is not realistic either because then the jobs will take 3600 longer to complete.

Adding every single file in the filesystem to the artifacts is not feasible Agreed. the web interface doesn't have the files as far as I can tel It has the artifacts. Is there no way to restart the container and connect to it? No, at least on my machine containers are getting removed. I do not see an option for non-removal only-stopping of docker containers in gitalb-runner configuration reference. sleep 3600 is not realistic I meant to temporary add it, diagnose the issue, and then remove. You could also just cat foo.log from the build for that matter.

I see, thanks for the help. I was able to at least add ./myScript.sh || cat foo.log to the CI job, which at least works for one case :) But in general it's not quite perfect since often times there are dozens of files that I need to inspect, and the job could take an hour or more before failing, so it's very troublesome.

Once again, I agree - it is troublesome. An hour job is a long job. If you have gitlab on premise, you might consider mounting a cache and optimizing for processing only modified files.
